# Colocar um botão para baixar um svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho a tag:

```
 <svg id="codBarras"></svg>
```

Nela é criado um código de barras em SVG pra mim. Preciso saber se tem um jeito de baixar esta imagem através de um botão. Se tem, como faço em js puro?

Comment: Seu SVG está `inline` dentro da tag <svg>? Ou ele é uma imagem tipo `<img src="codBarras.svg" alt="">` ?

Comment: Ele é gerado por um framework que gera código de barra, aparece na tag assim que eu digito um valor qualquer no input

Comment: No StackOverflow gringo tem umas resposta a respeito. Mas acho que esse artigo tb pode te interessar http://dinbror.dk/blog/how-to-download-an-inline-svg-as-jpg-or-png/

Comment: Consegui entender lá não